# inductive proof of geometric series

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I am stuck on understanding the inductive proof of geometric series. Specifically, I don't see how $ar^{k+1}$ equates to $\dfrac {(ar^{k+2}-ar^{k+1})}{(r-1)}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\frac{ar^{k+2}-ar^{k+1}}{r-1}=\frac{ar^{k+1}(r-1)}{r-1}=ar^{k+1}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\dfrac {(ar^{k+2}-ar^{k+1})}{(r-1)}$$
using this property :$a^{m+n}=a^m\cdot a^n$
$$\dfrac {(a\cdot r^k\cdot r^2-a\cdot r^k\cdot r^1)}{(r-1)}$$
$$\dfrac {a\cdot r^k\cdot r(r-1)}{(r-1)}$$
$$ar^{k+1}$$

Comment: That's it! Thanks for showing that property of exponents!